# Blueprint.js MultiSelect: how to enable scrolling?

Tags: blueprint

In Blueprint.js `MultiSelect` example at https://blueprintjs.com/docs/#select/multi-select , after clicking on search box, exactly 10 items are shown. We can scroll down to view the rest.

### How can I enable scrolling, and/or specify the maximum number of items displayed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the **MultiSelect** tag, add **popoverProps** props, then fill in **popoverClassName** with the custom css value:

```
.custom-class {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

<MultiSelect
    popoverProps={{
    popoverClassName: "custom-class",
  }}
/>
```